# $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb P)$ is isomorphic to $\mathrm{ Aut} (k(t) )$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space

$\def\Aut{\mathrm{Aut}}$I want to prove that the automorphism group of $\mathbb P^1$ it's isomorphic with the Moebius transformation with coefficients over the obvious field. I proved that the automorphism of $k(t)$ are of this form, If I prove that:
 $$\Aut(\mathbb P)\text{ is isomorphic to }\Aut (k(t) )$$
I'll be done. How can I do it, only using basic facts?

Comment: What's your definition of $\mathbb{P}^1$ and what's your definition of a morphism between projective varieties?

Answer (score 3):

If $f:\mathbb P^1\to \mathbb P^1$ is your automorphism and if $f({\infty})=b\neq \infty $, consider $g(z)=\frac {1}{z-b}$.
Then  $g\circ f$ sends $\infty $ to $\infty $. Thus  you may assume (replacing  $f$ by $g\circ f$ if necessary) that $f({\infty})={\infty}$.
You are then reduced to showing that the  restricted automorphism  $f\mid \mathbb A^1: \mathbb A^1 \to \mathbb A^1$ is given by $z\mapsto az+b$, which result you can probably handle.